# SQLite Bad Request Error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am attempting to import sms messages from a sqlite db into the sms inbox. The db is located on the SD card. I am getting a Bad Request error. The Sql statement is structured correctly. I am not sure what error is. Please help me find where the error is.

MainActivity snippet:

```
    private void importSms() {
    int id = 10;
    while(id < 10860) {  
        System.out.println("The id is " + id);
        String address = null;
        String body = null;
        dbHelper.returnAddress(id);
        dbHelper.returnBody(id);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("address", address);
        values.put("body", body);
        getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Importing sms number" + id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        id = id ++;
    }


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Finished import",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

DataBaseHelper snippet: (If need I can post the whole class it's not that large)

```
  public String returnAddress(int id) {
    System.out.println("returnAddress has been called");
    openDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

                String addressQuery = "SELECT address FROM sms WHERE _id = " + id;
                Cursor ca = db.rawQuery(addressQuery, null);
                ca.moveToFirst();
                String address = ca.getString(1);
                return address;


}
public String returnBody(int id) {
    System.out.println("returnBody has been called");
    openDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();


                String bodyQuery = "SELECT body FROM sms WHERE _id = " + id;
                Cursor cb = db.rawQuery(bodyQuery, null);
                cb.moveToFirst();
                String body = cb.getString(2);
                return  body;


}
```

Error Messages:

```
09-18 19:09:33.466: I/System.out(2729): The id is 10
 09-18 19:09:33.466: I/System.out(2729): returnAddress has been called
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/CursorWindow(2729): Bad request for field slot 0,1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 1
 09-18 19:09:33.526: D/AndroidRuntime(2729): Shutting down VM
 09-18 19:09:33.526: W/dalvikvm(2729): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 1 failed
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at com.mobile.sms.testing.DataBaseHelper.returnAddress(DataBaseHelper.java:64)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at com.mobile.sms.testing.MainActivity.importSms(MainActivity.java:53)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at com.mobile.sms.testing.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:47)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at com.mobile.sms.testing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 09-18 19:09:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 09-18 19:09:35.676: I/Process(2729): Sending signal. PID: 2729 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are trying to get the string from a non-existent column.

I think this might be what you need:

```java
String addressQuery = "SELECT _id, address FROM sms WHERE _id = ?";
Cursor ca = db.rawQuery(addressQuery, id);
ca.moveToFirst();
int addressColumn = ca.getColumnIndexOrThrow ("address");
String address = ca.getString(addressColumn);
```

This code parametrizes your id as well as lets you know you are getting the right column.

Although, `IllegalStateException` makes me wonder if the db is readable

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your query, you are only returning one column, and the columns in a cursor are numbered from 0.  So using `String address = ca.getString(1);` is essentially asking it to pull the data from the (non-existent) second column... and the same with your body method.

Change those bits of code and I believe your issue will be solved.

```
String address = ca.getString(0);
String body = cb.getString(0);
```

Even better, do as pjco suggested and use the `getColumnIndexOrThrow` method, as then if you insert or delete other elements into the cursor (thus potentially changing the column id of the data you want), you don't have to change the column id throughout the rest of your app:

```
String address = ca.getString(ca.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
String body = ca.getString(ca.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
```